# $R$ be an integral domain and $M$ a torsion free module and $a\ne0$ be an element in $R$. Then prove that $M\cong aM$

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, modules

$M$ is torsion free means $\text{Tor}(M)=\{m\in M|\ \exists r\ne0\ \text{such that } rm=0\}=0$.

Now I define $f:M\to aM$ by $f(m)=am$. Using $\text{Tor}(M)=0$ and $a\ne0$, I can prove $\text{Ker}(f)=0$. But I'm unable to prove the surjectivity of $f$. I guess I need to use the fact that $R$ is integral domain.

Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: any element of $aM$ is of the form $am$ such that $m\in M$. So $m\in M$ is a preimage of $am\in  aM$.

Comment: I guess your confusion was that you wanted to prove surjectivity with the full codomain $M$.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I'm so dumb.